# "The system cannot find the file specified" on custom tool

Tags: ms-release-management

I've created a custom tool for MRM using a powershell script that I've tested as working on my local machine.

The script has been added as a resource to the tool and I am calling the script by the following command `-command ./KeepBuild-RM.ps1` plus the parameters.

I've added the action based on this tool (essentially a pass through to the tool) as the 1st action in the release path.

When the release runs it seems to instantly fail with "The system cannot find the file specified".

When checking the temp location on the server it looks like the tool wasn't copied over as part of the drop.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing the copy to fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **command** field should be `powershell.exe`. The **argument** field should be `-command ./KeepBuild-RM.ps1`

If you really put `-command ./KeepBuild-RM.ps1` in the command field, it's trying to run exactly that text on the command line.